# HTML5 Video flashes white before video loading

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I have a a `video` element that I'm changing dynamically `src` to other videos on choice. However it keeps having white background before video loads - that's only if I activate controls though!

```html
<video id="video" width="1920" height="1080" preload="auto" controls="true" webkit-playsinline>
    <source src="videos/3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

```js
$("#firstButton").click(function () {
  $("video").attr("src", "videos/1.mp4");
  $('.langversion').html('');
  $('.langversion').append('First Text')

  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");

  playButton.innerHTML = "<i class='material-icons'>play_circle_outline</i>";
  active = 1;

  var video = document.getElementById("video");
});
```

I have tried to put a `background-color` on the video element but helps nothing. I also have tried to add border bottom to `video` element with no success.

```
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
```

I honestly have no idea where does it come from and how to prevent it.

Comment: Hi ! Please give more code, explaining hw you are changing the sec for instance

Comment: $("#firstButton").click(function () {

  $("video").attr("src", "videos/1.mp4");
  $('.langversion').html('');
  $('.langversion').append('First Text')
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
  playButton.innerHTML = "<i class='material-icons'>play_circle_outline</i>";
  active = 1;
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
 


 });

Comment: Please update your question and use the code flag

Comment: I just edited your code into the question. (It's best to put that into the question instead of posting it as a comment.) Was the Google Chrome tag indicating that this issue only appears on Chrome? Have you tested it on any other browsers?

Comment: I'm sorry, was in rush yesterday.
Yeah, it happends only in google chrome.

Comment: @AndrewMyers Just tested on chromium, it just happend on chrome

Answer (score 0):

The video element is transparent in Chrome when loading the new `src`. I added a background colour on a wrapper element so that shows through and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: actually this question is 4 years old and I think they changed alot since then in Chrome, but didnt check again on this exact question